# disabling onclick with jQuery until page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that works `onclick`. The problem is that it fails to work if the page is not fully loaded, so I want to disable it until the page is loaded and then enable it with jQuery.

```
<div class="btn btn-block" onclick="launchAction()">
<div class="launch"><i class="icon-launch"></i></div>
Launch
</div>
```

How would I do that? I tried to `disable` it but that didn't stop onclick from working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

```
<div class="btn btn-block" id="mybutton">
<div class="launch"><i class="icon-launch"></i></div>
Launch
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mybutton").click(function () {
      launchAction();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with jquery, you can just enable the click event when the page has been loaded.

```
<div class="btn btn-block" id="myBtn">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // DOM Content has been loaded

    $('#myBtn').on('click', launchAction);
});
</script>
```